# How can i show and hide div

Tags: jquery, css

When user click on `MoreDiv` `HiddenDiv` will be show and when click again or clicked on any where of page `hiddenDiv` div
 must be hidden More

this is my css

```
.hiddenDiv {
  margin-left:505px;
  margin-top:25px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9876567890;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}
.hiddenDiv ul { 
  list-style:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.hiddenDiv ul li {
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
} .hiddenDiv ul li:hover {
  background-color:#4681C5;
}
```

This is my div

```
<div class="hiddenDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Add favorites</li>
    <li>Give a Gift</li>
    <li>Block</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('div.moreDiv').click(function() {
    $(".hiddenDiv").css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: my Z-index goes up in 100's and I thought that was extreme!

Comment: @Norse. You should get a badge for that glance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `show` method

The below script will show when you click on the more link and hide it if you click anywhere in the window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).click(function() {        
    ShowHide();
   });

   $('div.moreDiv').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      ShowHide(true);
   });
});

function ShowHide(isFirstTime)
{
     var disp= $(".hiddenDiv").css("display");
     if((disp=="none")&&(isFirstTime))
     {                            
         $(".hiddenDiv").show()             
     }
     else
     {
          $(".hiddenDiv").hide()
     }        
}
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/R7VRq/31/

Comment: Thank you Shyju , i use that one.

Comment: i got problem because  moreDiv is a class and there are many .moreDiv div in the same page, when i click one div all div show and hide :) , how can i fix it?

Comment: @mtarslan I encourage you to post it as a new question **with relevant Markup and Script**

Comment: f*** system give error :`It does not meet our quality standards.` so i coulnd't open question

Comment: @mtarslan : Did you post a new question ?

Answer (score 4):

Use toggle method to show and hide div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.moreDiv').click(function() {
        $(".hiddenDiv").toggle() });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7VRq/24/

Answer (score 1):

In this case the DIV has the id of DIV1 as you can see in the javascript. Just use javascript no jquery is needed, this is easier anyway.

```
<div class="moreDiv">More </div><div  id="DIV1" class="hiddenDiv"><ul><li>Add favorites</li><li>Give a Gift</li><li>Block</li></ul></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function ShowDIV(){
if (DIV1.style.display=="none") DIV1.style.display="block";
else DIV1.style.display="none";
}
```

Html to hid or show div:

```
<a href="#" onClick="ShowDIV();"><button>Show DIV</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/akeqeb/3/edit)*

- Use `.toggle()` to toggle 'display' states.
- Add an event listener and use `.stopPropagation()`. That will prevent the click event to be passed (bubbled) to your element ancestors.
- Add an `if` statement to check on `body` click - to see if the popup is visible- an hide it if true:

jQ:

```
  $('div.moreDiv').click(function(e){ // 'e' = event listener
       e.stopPropagation();    // event - stop propagation to body, parents.
       $(".hiddenDiv").toggle();   // toggle 'display' states             
  });
  
  $('body').click(function(){     
      if( $(".hiddenDiv").is(':visible') ){    // check if element is visible
          $(".hiddenDiv").hide();              // if true - hide it
      }
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { 
    $('div.moreDiv').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('showing_hidden_div')) {
            $(this).removeClass('showing_hidden_div');
            $('.hiddenDiv').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('showing_hidden_div');
            $(".hiddenDiv").show();
        }
    });
});
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method in jquery for hiding elements.
Use `body` onclick to hide your div.